# laravel dropdown value restriction based on roles

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have status select box with option New,Re-new,Delete . have roles admin,student,teacher. Now for admin all three select option can list where as for student and teacher I want to hide Delete option from dropdown.

How to do it in laravel ? Can it be a part of validation rule ? or I have to generate with if n else. For role and permission I am using entrust and confide.

```
{{Former::select('status'->options(Subject::getAllowedoption('status'))}}
```

in model class under $rule I have the option defined New|Re-new|Delete and I am trying to find a way to restrict option Delete for role teacher.

Comment: You might want to post the code you already have.

Comment: Post your Subject::getAllowedoption($var) method